# Skinning telerik's RadEdior ::Can't find ConfigDefault.xml as mentioned in this article

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, telerik

http://blogs.xd.com.au/2010/07/15/radeditor-background-color/

I also can't find no EditorCustom.css and CustomOverride.css file..Where on earth are these stored? Now how am I supposed to fix the background when I can't find these files!? Where do I need to look for them? Plz help..thnx

I am using demo version of telerik btw.is that why I cant find these files?

What's this DotNetNuke 5+ builds mentioned in this article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal version of the editor does not have any external files. All CSS and images are stored inside the Telerik.Web.UI assembly as embedded resources. The article you mention is related to the DNN editor provider for RadEditor and the files discussed there are only present when you use DotNetNuke and that specific provider.

Comment: ok so the only option I have at hand is to specifically include Custom Skin's css files in my RadEditor tags ?? No way to set the Skin globally that will affect ALL my aspx pages that use RadEditor??